# Failing comparison of floats NaNs on STM32F407 CORTEX-M4

Tags: c, gcc, c99, cortex-m, stm32f4

I'm trying to compare two floats returned from `nanf("1")` and the program is not entering `if` block.

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile float f;
    volatile float ff;
    uint32_t* view1;
    uint32_t* view2;

    view1 = ((uint32_t*)&f);
    view2 = ((uint32_t*)&ff);

    f = nanf("1");
    ff = nanf("1");

    if(f == ff)
    {
        f = 0;
    }

    while(1);
}
```

Debugger shows `f` and `ff` (through `view1` and `view2`) variable has quiet NaN values (`QNaN == 0x7FC00001`).

**Compiler:**

> gcc version 4.8.3 20131129 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision
>   205641]  (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)

**Flags for compiler:**

> -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 
>   -std=c99 -DSTM32F407VETx -DSTM32 -DSTM32F4 -DDEBUG 
>   -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c

**Flags for Linker:**

> -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 
>   -Wl,--gc-sections -lm

**And here is the output assembly (can't paste this in code block):**

```
if(f == ff)
080129b4:   ldr     r3, [pc, #32]   ; (0x80129d8 <main+92>)
080129b6:   vldr    s14, [r3]
080129ba:   ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (0x80129e0 <main+100>)
080129bc:   vldr    s15, [r3]
080129c0:   vcmp.f32        s14, s15
080129c4:   vmrs    APSR_nzcv, fpscr
080129c8:   bne.n   0x80129d2 <main+86>

f = 0;
080129ca:   ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (0x80129d8 <main+92>)
080129cc:   mov.w   r2, #0
080129d0:   str     r2, [r3, #0]

while(1);
080129d2:   b.n     0x80129d2 <main+86>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing numbers, `==` produces true (1) if and only if the two operands are equal numbers. NaNs are not numbers, so they can never be equal numbers. Whenever `x` or `y` is a NaN, `x == y` always produces false (0) even if they are the same NaN.

If you need to determine whether two NaNs are identical, you can compare the bytes of their representations:

```
if (memcmp(&f, &ff, sizeof f) == 0)
```

### Notes

- `memcmp` is declared in `<string.h>`.
- Your code `view1 = ((uint32_t*)&f);` suggests you were using `*view1` to examine the bytes of `f` as a `uint32_t`. Do not do this, because it is not supported by the C standard and there are easy supported ways. To examine the bytes of `f` as a `uint32_t`, you can use `uint32_t view1; memcpy(&view1, &f, sizeof view1));` or `uint32_t view1 = (union { float x; uint32_t y; }) { f } .y;`.
- `volatile` is not needed for this, especially once you stop the unsupported aliasing. If `f` and `ff` are `volatile`, then the `memcmp` needs casts: `memcmp((void *) &f, (void *) &ff, sizeof f)`.
- Comparing this way could produce false negatives if the `float` type has padding bits. (Two NaNs that are identical semantically could have different padding bits.) However, this would be unusual, if not nonexistent, in modern C implementations. Since you are targeting a particular implementation that uses a 32-bit floating-point type, it cannot have padding bits if its C type is 32 bits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sure what you mean the `view1 = ((uint32_t*)&f);` is not supported by the C standard? I thought this is typical C construct.

Comment: @Pawcio: C 2018 6.5 7 says an object shall be accessed only as a compatible type, a qualified version of it, a signed or unsigned version of it, an aggregate or union that contains one of those, or a character type. For a `float` object, `uint32_t` is none of those. Converting the pointer itself is okay (if there is no alignment issue, which can also result in behavior not defined by the standard), but accessing the object through that pointer would violate 6.5 7.